# jquery ui autocompleter and angular directive testing using jasmine

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have created directive for autocomplete feature and user jquery ui autocompleter to get the autocomplete feature.

```
  var directive = module.exports = function(constants,$parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var searchFunction = $parse(attr.searchFunction);
            var setValueFunc = $parse(attr.ngModel).assign;
            var autocompleteclass = attr.autoCompleteClass;
            scope.$watch(attr.autoCompleteData, function () {
                element.autocomplete('option', {
                    source: scope.$eval(attr.autoCompleteData)
                });
            });

            element.autocomplete({
                source: scope.$eval(attr.autoCompleteData),
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    setValueFunc(scope, ui.item.value);
                    var originalEvent = event.originalEvent;
                    while (originalEvent.originalEvent !== void 0) {
                        originalEvent = originalEvent.originalEvent;
                    }
                    if (originalEvent.type === constants.CLICK_EVENT) {
                        searchFunction(scope,{selectedText: scope.$eval(attr.autoCompleteModel)});
                    }
                },
                focus: function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }).autocomplete('widget').addClass('dropdown-menu').addClass(autocompleteclass);

            element.keyup(function(event) {
                if (event.which === constants.ENTER_KEY_CODE) {
                    element.autocomplete('close');
                    searchFunction(scope,{selectedText:  scope.$eval(attr.autoCompleteModel)});
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });

        }
    };
};
directive.$inject = ['constants','$parse'];
```

I want to write test cases using jasmine. I can test keyup event with enter keypress. But I am unable to test select event. Second point was, I have passed 4 elements for the same. If I try to search li inside ul element, then I got the li elements length equals to 0.

please find test case for the same.

```
describe('Directive test', function () {

    var $scope, $compile, autoCompleteElement, $document;

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, _$compile_, _$document_) {
        $scope = $rootScope;
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $document = _$document_;

        $scope.dummyFunction = function(){};
        $scope.searchedFun = function(searchText) {
            $scope.dummyFunction();
        };

        $scope.names = ['name 1', 'name 2', 'name 3', 'name 4'];
        var template = angular.element(
            '<form name="form"><input type="text" auto-complete ' +
            '   class="form-control search-input"'+ 
            '   data-ng-model="search.text" name="name" ' +
            '   auto-complete-data="names" '+
            '   auto-complete-model="searchText" '+ 
            '   search-func="searchedFun(searchText)" ' +
            '/> </form>'
        );
        $scope.search = {text: null};
        autoCompleteElement = $compile(template)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();

    }));

    it('should call search function on click in input box', inject(function($rootScope) {
        $scope.search.text = 'q';
        autoCompleteElement.scope().$apply();
        expect($document.find('body').find('ul')).toBeDefined();
    }));

    it('should select the data from option and call the function on enter event', inject( function($rootScope) {
        $scope.search.text = 'q';
        var event = angular.element.Event('keyup');
        event.which = 13;
        autoCompleteElement.find('input').trigger(event);
        $rootScope.$apply();
        expect($document.find('body').find('#ui-id-1').attr('style')).toContain('display: none;');
    }));

    it('should select the data from option and call the function on select event', inject( function($rootScope) {
        $scope.search.text = 'q';
        var event = angular.element.Event('keypress');
        //autoCompleteElement.find('input').trigger(event);
        $document.find('body').find('#ui-id-1').trigger(event);
        $rootScope.$apply();
        expect($document.find('body').find('#ui-id-1').attr('style')).toContain('display: none;');
    }));
});
```

please guide me. How to check the ng-model is updated? How to check on select event the controller's function is called? how to check select event?

Thanks in advance.
Jay

Answer (score 1):

> How to check the ng-model is updated?

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
   ctrl.$viewChangeListeners.push(function() {
   /*...*/
   }
  )
/*...*/
}
```

> How to check on select event the controller's function is called?

```
select: function foo(event, ui) {
   console.log("Function called is: " + this.name);
   /*...*/
   }
```

> how to check select event?

```
select: function(event, ui) {
  $scope.$broadcast("selectCalled", { newValue: $scope.id++, oldValue: $scope.id });
  $scope.$on("selectCalled", function(event, options) {
    console.log(String().concat("Event: ", event,"Old: ", options.oldValue, "New: ", options.newValue);
    /*...*/
    }
  )
});
```

and Jasmine:

```
it('should call controller', function() {
  compileInput('<input type="text" ng-model="name" />');
  var ctrl = inputElm.controller('ngModel');

  browserTrigger(inputElm, 'keydown', {target: inputElm[0]});
  inputElm.val('f');
  browserTrigger(inputElm, 'change');
  expect(inputElm).toBeDirty();

  ctrl.$setPristine();
  scope.$apply();

  $browser.defer.flush();
  expect(inputElm).toBePristine();
});
```

**References**

- [AngularJS: inputSpec.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/test/ng/directive/inputSpec.js)